# Working with table types

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

I have created a Table Value Type,
which is created fine.

```
CREATE TYPE [ContactTemplate] AS TABLE (
    [Email]             VARCHAR(100),
    [FirstName]         VARCHAR(50),
    [LastName]          VARCHAR(50)
)
GO
```

Then, when i try to create  a procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_ProcessContact]
 (  @Email      VARCHAR(100),
    @FirstName  VARCHAR(50),
    @LastName   VARCHAR(50),
    @Contact    ContactTemplate READONLY)
    as 
    Begin
    -------
    End
```

I keep getting error at

```
@Contact    ContactTemplate READONLY" The parameter @Contact  cannot
be declared READONLY since it is not a table valued parameter
```

I have tried many things, removing `dbo`, brackets etc., still cant get it to work. Help please..

Comment: Are you adding a C# type into a stored procedure: `ContactTemplate `, that isn't going to work unless your working on a CLR sproc.

Comment: I've tried running this and I don't get any errors. The stored procedure is created successfully. Are you sure your using the same database when running both scripts?

Comment: Yeah same DB. I am wondering if it has to do with MSSQL 2012?

Comment: Try this: Edit -> IntelliSense -> Refresh Local Cache -- If you just defined the table type, your symbol table doesn't know it yet.  Or, create the type, exit from SSMS, and reopen.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this: Edit -> IntelliSense -> Refresh Local Cache -- If you just defined the table type, your symbol table doesn't know it yet. Or, create the type, exit from SSMS, and reopen.